# How to change font and font size in scrollable text view in xcode?

Tags: text, view, fonts, size, scrollable

How can I change the font and font size of my text in a scrollable text view in xCode? Will this require code or can I do it only in Interface Builder?

Answer (score 1):

3 years late but still might help someone :) 
If you want to edit the font from storyboard:
Change the text type from Plain to Attributed.
Then you have font options, If you want more mark the text then right click and you'll have more options.

[image]